# ALBの名前解決をする仕組みを教えて下さい

Tags: aws, dns, amazon-elb

**■背景**
オンプレ環境に設置したサーバー類をAWS環境に移行するための設計をしています。

社内設置のクライアントから、VPNまたは専用線でつないだAWS環境に設置したWEBサーバーにHTTPアクセスすることを想定しています。
クライアントは社内ドメインに所属しており、社内DNSサーバーを参照しています。

**■質問**
ALBを設置してWEBサーバーへの負荷分散を行う場合、クライアントはどうやってALBの名前解決をするのでしょうか。

ネットで調べたところ、ALBは固定IPを持てないとのことでした。
そのため、クライアントはALBのDNS名を指定してアクセスするものと思います。
おそらくRoute53が、ALB作成時に割り当てられたDNS名と、動的に割り振られているIPを都度紐づけているのかなと想像しましたが、それだと、クライアントはDNSとしてRoute53を参照に行かないとALBの名前解決ができないことになってしまうと思います。
このあたりの仕組みが、AWSはまだ勉強中のためよくわかりません。

Answer (score 1):

内部向け ALB エンドポイントの名前解決は VPC のプライベート IPアドレスが返りますが、この DNS レコードは、VPC 内部 DNS サーバーだけでなく、外向きの DNS サーバーでも参照できるようです。

[外部dnsでaws内部elbの名前解決が出来るか？](https://blog.putise.com/%E5%A4%96%E9%83%A8dns%E3%81%A7aws%E5%86%85%E9%83%A8elb%E3%81%AE%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D%E8%A7%A3%E6%B1%BA%E3%81%8C%E5%87%BA%E6%9D%A5%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8B%EF%BC%9F/)

なので、ALB エンドポイント名そのままでアクセスするか、CNAME で ALB エンドポイントを参照する適当なホスト名を社内 DNS サーバーに登録すればいいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

> クライアントはDNSとしてRoute53を参照に行かないとALBの名前解決ができないことになってしまうと思います。

AWS以前の問題として、インターネット・DNSの仕組みを理解していないように見受けられます。DNSの動作に関してご自身でも勉強なさってください。例えば[インターネット10分講座：DNS](https://www.nic.ad.jp/ja/newsletter/No22/080.html)では「DNSにおける問い合わせの流れ」で図解説明されていますが、一般のPCではDNSサーバーとして「DNSサーバに問い合わせを行うためのサーバ」を設定します。「DNSサーバに問い合わせを行うためのサーバ」はルートサーバーをはじめ世界中のDNSサーバーへ接続を行いアドレス情報を取得します。もちろん、`amazonaws.com`等のAWSのアドレスについてはAmazon Route 53が用意しているDNSサーバーから取得します。

ですので、「DNSサーバに問い合わせを行うためのサーバ」＝質問文中の「社内DNSサーバー」がALBを含む世界中のアドレスを取得できるよう設定されていればそれまでです。